# Jquery datatable version 1.10 affecting Bootstrap version 5.1 dropdown component

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, datatables, bootstrap-5, datatables-1.10

In my website i'm using bootstrap v5.1 and datatable v1.10 in my project. But this datatable version affect the bootstrap dropdown. The dropdown is not opening. Also no errors throwing, when i remove the latest version and adding the old version of the datatable it's working fine. If anyone having solution for this problem please help me.

Here I added my UI html code, please find the dropdown initialization. It's a sample bootstrap nav bar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" id="homeHeader">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="padding: 0;">
            <img src="images/logo-text.png" style="height: 36px;">
<!--            <div style="display: inline-block;font-weight: 600;color: #ffffff;">Ledger Book</div>-->
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown" id="profileDropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                        <div style="font-size: 14px;font-weight: 600;display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;" id="fullName"></div>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Profile</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i> Settings</a></li>
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>


    </div>
</nav>
```

Here I mentioned my data table initialization with a function. But the previous version of the dropdown is working fine. When I using the v1.10 with bootstrap 5.1 that dropdown not working properly.

```
function getExpenseList() {
        
            const fields = [
                {
                    mData: 'expense_ts',
                    sTitle: 'Paid Time',
                    "orderable": true,
                    bSortable : true,
                    mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<div>' + row["paid_date"] + ' ' + row["paid_time"] + '</div>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    mData: 'amount',
                    sTitle: 'Amount',
                    mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<div style="text-align: right;"><i class="fa fa-inr" style="color: #666666;"></i> ' + Number(data).toFixed(2) + '</div>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    mData: 'expense_details',
                    sTitle: 'Expense Details',
                    bSortable : false,
                    "orderable": false,
                    mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                        return data;
                    }
                },
                {
                    mData: 'payment_type',
                    sTitle: 'Payment Type',
                    bSortable : false,
                    "orderable": false,
                    mRender: function (data, type, row) {
        
                        let typeHtml  = '<span><i class="fa fa-money"></i> '+data+'</span>';
                        if (data === "Cash") {
                            typeHtml = '<span><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Cash</span>';
                        } else if (data === "Online") {
                            typeHtml = '<span><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Online</span>';
                        }else{
                            typeHtml = '<span><i class="fa fa-money"></i> Other</span>';
                        }
        
                        return '<div>' + typeHtml + '</div>';
                    }
                },
                {
                    mData: 'ledger_name',
                    sTitle: 'Actions',
                    bSortable : false,
                    "orderable": false,
                    "data": null,
                    mRender: function (data, type, row) {
                        return '<div style="text-transform: capitalize;text-align: center;">' +
                                '<button class="btn btn-outline-primary th-action" onclick="editExpense(\''+row["_id"]+'\')"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></button>' +
                                '<button class="btn btn-outline-primary th-action" onclick="deleteExpense(\''+row["_id"]+'\')" style="margin-left: 6px;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>' +
                            '</div>';
                    }
                }
            ];
        
            const queryParams = {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [],
                        "should": [],
                        "filter": {
                            "range": {
                                "expense_ts": {
                                    "gte": new Date(startDate).getTime(),
                                    "lte": new Date(endDate).getTime()
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    }
                },
                "sort": [{ "expense_ts": { "order": "asc" } }]
            }
        
            $.fn.dataTable.ext.buttons.refresh = {
                text: 'Refresh'
                , action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                    dt.clear().draw();
                    dt.ajax.reload();
                }
            };
        
            setTimeout(function(){
                if (expenseTable) {
                    expenseTable.destroy();
                    $("#expenseList").html("");
                }
        
                expenseTable = $("#expenseList").DataTable({
                    fixedHeader: true,
                    responsive: true,
                    select: true,
                    paging: true,
                    searching: true,
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    lengthMenu: [
                        [5, 10, 50, 100],
                        [5, 10, 50, 100]
                    ],
                    buttons: [
                        'print',
                        {
                            text: 'Refresh',
                            action: function ( e, dt, node, config ) {
                                getExpenseList();
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    aaSorting: [
                        [0, 'desc']
                    ],
                    aoColumns : fields,
                    bServerSide : true,
                    sAjaxSource : API_BASE_PATH+'expense/list',
                    fnServerData : function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
                        let keyName = fields[oSettings.aaSorting[0][0]]
        
                        let sortingJson = {};
                        sortingJson[keyName['mData']] = {
                            "order": oSettings.aaSorting[0][1]
                        };
                        queryParams.sort = [sortingJson];
                        queryParams.query['bool']['must'] = [];
                        queryParams.query['bool']['should'] = [];
                        delete queryParams.query['bool']["minimum_should_match"];
                        queryParams['size'] = oSettings._iDisplayLength;
                        queryParams['from'] = oSettings._iDisplayStart;
        
                        queryParams.query['bool']['must'].push({
                            "match": {
                                "user_id": USER_OBJ["username"]
                            }
                        })
        
                        skyLoader("show");
        
                        oSettings.jqXHR = $.ajax({
                            "dataType": 'json',
                            "contentType": 'application/json',
                            "type": "POST",
                            "url": sSource,
                            "data": JSON.stringify(queryParams),
                            success: function (data) {
                                skyLoader("hide");
                                let resultData = {};
        
                                if(data["status"]){
                                    let resultData = data.result.data;
                                    resultData['draw'] = oSettings.iDraw;
                                    EXPENSE_LIST = resultData['data'];
                                    fnCallback(resultData);
                                }
                            }
                        });
        
                    }
                });
            }, 400);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution, It's a datatable problem. For the latest version it's working fine. So if you are using the v1.10 with bootstrap5.1 just remove it and use the v1.11.5. from below given url.

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js